# send data and events from pthread to a QT QApplication with QLabel and QImage

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface, pthreads

The question is about interfacing an existing C, pthread-based application, with QT GUI. It seems a simple task to do, but while I have searched (both on Internet and through trial&error), I did not find an acceptable solution.

Now, the application makes heavily use of a pre-existing C library, to which I have no access to modify its code.

Basically, the pre-existing library implements a loop, that calls in a periodic manner some functions (with some data). It is only those functions (function pointers) that I am able to define.

In a complete application, the pre-existing library loop calls those functions (aka "init", "process" and "uninit") in the following manner:

```
 init(f);
 process(f);
 process(f);
 ...
 process(f);
 ...
 process(f);
 uninit(f);
```

The "f" is a structure that allows keeping relevant data from call to call and "init" and "uninint" functions serve to set up and to destroy data allocated by f.

Now, the process() function makes some computationa nd the final result is a matrix, that I would like to display, as an image, inside a QT GUI (as simply as it gets).

However, the QT GUI has its own, blocking, event-loop, aka myApp.exec().

So, to achieve that, I created a new thread (pthread) in my "init" function that will first fill "f" fields with relevant data and then enter the myApp.exec() loop. The myApp is a simple QApplication containing a QLabel that display a QPixmap constructed from a QImage that I am able to fille its "bits()" data with the computed data (using some mapping irrelevant here).

After that, the "process" function makes its successive computations, updates the "bits" data of the QImage (the "bits" pointer is known through the f structure) and then should force the GUI to update itself.

Here are some code snippets:

```
 init(f){
 ...
 pthread_create(&(f->qt_tid),NULL,&qtimgdisplay_main_thread,f);
 ...
}

 process(f){
 ...
 do_computation();
 do_ update(f->bits);
 f->myLabel->repaint();
...
}

static void *qtimgdisplay_main_thread(void *arg){
    FStructure *f = (FStructure *)arg;

    char  arg0[] = "programName";
    char  arg1[] = "arg";
    char  arg2[] = "another arg";
    char* argv[] = { &arg0[0], &arg1[0], &arg2[0], NULL };
    int   argc   = (int)(sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0])) - 1;

    f->myApp = new QApplication(argc, &argv[0]);

    //we create a image
    QImage image(f->winwidth,f->winheight,QImage::Format_RGB32);

    f->bits=image.bits(); //pointer to the underlying data image

    f->myLabel=new QLabel();
    f->myLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    f->myLabel->show();

    f->myApp->exec();

    return NULL;
}
```

Although somewhat working (execpts some random segmentation faults), the problem with that solution is that it (correctly) displays:

QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

which is perfectly true, since QWidgets are not re-entrant.

So, then I tried to post a Repaint() message to myApp, in an asynchronous manner (I still have to imagine how to emit a signal from my process() to the QLabel myLabel), by replacing, inside "process":

```
 f->myLabel->repaint();
```

with:

```
 f->myApp->postEvent(f->myLabel,new QPaintEvent(f->myLabel->rect()));
```

The disastrous result is that the QT GUI does not updates itself; more, console displays:

QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent

Finally, I tried to replace the same above line with something "smarter" (that I found here: http://www.qtforum.org/article/18253/qpaintevent-problem-in-qt4.html), namely:

```
    QPaintEvent *pe = new QPaintEvent(f->myLabel->rect());
    f->myLabel->setAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_InPaintEvent, true);
    f->myApp->sendEvent(s->myLabel,f->myLabel->rect());
    f->myLabel->setAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_InPaintEvent, false);
```

The fantastic result is that it does not even compile:

error: no matching function for call to ‘QApplication::sendEvent(QLabel*&, QRect)’

I am lost. Could anybody, please, help?

These are some possible solutions that I contemplated:

1) making qtimgdisplay_main_thread a QThread thread instead of a pthread thread, although I am not sure this will be of any help;

2) trying to emit some signals from my "process" to the f->myApp or to f->myLabel but I have no idea how to do that since "process" is running on a non-QThread (and there is no way to access the parent thread)

3) create and destroying a new QApplication, with all associated QLabel and QImage inside of "process", but that is simply overwhelming and idiot to do under normal circumstances.

I thank you for bearing reading all this. Please try to provide me a hint through code (not another documentation), if possible.

Edit: It appears that if I use:

```
f->myLabel->update();
```

instead of:

```
 f->myLabel->repaint();
```

inside my "process".

Can anybody confirm this is the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: for anybody who could be interested in the same topic, please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10882705/1284631 for a very nice solution provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329652/kuba-ober (using the `QCoreApplication::postEvent` method) and my own solution, which boils down to writing and instantiating a special-purpose QObject-derived method-commanded signal-emitting class for interfacing with QT (ie. a class whose methods are called just like any other C++ methods, but the only useful thing they do is to emit signals towards the QT QObjects).