# Am I forced to use pthread_cond_broadcast (over pthread_cond_signal) in order to guarantee that *my* thread is woken up?

Tags: c, qt, pthreads

In the context of interfacing some QT GUI thread (a pthread thread) with some C code, I stumbled over the following problem: I launch the QT Gui thread and, before my C thread resuming its path, I need to make sure that all the graphical objects inside the QT Gui thread had been constructed and they are valid QObjects (since the C code will call `QObject:connect()` on those).

Introduction let aside, the waiting is made through a `pthread_cond_wait()` + a condition variable + an associated mutex in the C thread:

```
int isReady=0;
pthread_mutex_lock(&conditionReady_mutex);
while(isReady==0) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&conditionReady_cv, &conditionReady_mutex);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&conditionReady_mutex);
```

On the other hand, the QT Gui thread constructs its graphical objects and then signals it with:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&conditionReady_mutex);
isReady=1;
pthread_cond_broadcast(&conditionReady_cv);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&conditionReady_mutex);
```

Basic stuff, as you see. But the question is: in the Qt Gui thread, I've been using the `pthread_cond_broadcast()`, in order to make sure that my C thread is woken up, for sure. Yes, in my current application, I only have a C thread and a Qt Gui thread, and `pthread_cond_signal()` should do the job of waking up the C thread (since it is guaranteed to wake up at least one thread, and the C thread is the only one).

But, in a more general context, let's say I have three C threads, but I want one (or two) of them to be woken up. A (two) specific thread(s). How do I ensure that?

If I use `pthread_cond_signal()`, that could simply wake up only the third thread, which would completely miss the point, since the one thread of interest for me is not woken up. OTOH, waking up all the threads, even those which are unneeded, through `pthread_cond_broadcast()`, that would be overkill.

There is a way to tell `pthread_cond_signal()` which thread to wake up?

Or, should I introduce more condition variables in order to have a finer granularity over the groups of threads that are woken up with `pthread_cond_broadcast()`?

Thank you.

Comment: The way it'd be normally solved is to instantiate the GUI first in `int main(...)`, and only afterwards start the thread.

Comment: @Kuba Ober: That won't be possible. For library reasons, the main thread should have nothing to do with a GUI thread. I do not even have the control of main(), that's all coded inside a library that I am using. I am forced to create the GUI on another thread, exactly to not block the first one. I also had to create by hand the command line parameters for the QApplication constructor.

Comment: This won't work on OS X, and is currently not supported by Qt. It happens to work on Windows, and perhaps Unix systems, but it's a happy coincidence, unfortunately. A hack. That third party library was designed by some bozos :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you require a specific thread to be woken up then you either need to broadcast the wakeup, or use a separate condition variable for that thread.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is in line with what I was thinking, but a confirmation is helpful to have.

Answer (score 4):

### Unsafe Manners

Calling any generic QWidget method directly from a different thread is unsafe, because the behavior of Qt and underlying C++-generated code in undefined. It may launch a nuclear first strike. You have been warned. Thus you cannot call `QWidget::update()`, `QLabel::setText(...)`, or any other such methods from a separate thread unless you use safe interthread communication offered by Qt.

#### Wrong

```
// in a separate thread
widget->update();
widget->setText("foo");
```

#### Right

```
// in a separate thread
// using QMetaObject::invokeMethod(widget, "update") is unoptimal
QCoreApplication::postEvent(widget, new QEvent(QEvent::UpdateRequest),
                            Qt::LowEventPriority);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(widget, "setText", Q_ARG(QString, "foo"));
```

### On Interthread Communication

A trivial way of communicating with a thread that contains some QObjects involves posting events to it via the static `QCoreApplication::postEvent()` method. The GUI thread is a common example of a thread where a whole bunch of QObjects reside. Using `postEvent()` is always thread safe. This method does not care *at all* which thread it's called from.

There are various static methods scattered across Qt that internally use `postEvent()`. Their key signature is that they, too, will be static! The `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(...)` family is such an example.

When you connect signals to slots in QObjects that live in different threads, a queued connection is used. With such a connection, every time the signal is emitted, a `QMetaCallEvent` is constructed and posted to the target QObject, using -- you guessed it right -- `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`.

So, connecting a signal from a QObject in some non-GUI thread to the `QWidget::update()` slot is safe, because internally such a connection uses `postEvent()` to propagate the signals across the thread barrier. The event loop in the GUI thread will pick it up and execute an actual call to the `QWidget::update()` on your label. Fully thread safe.

### Optimizations

The only problem with using a signal-slot connection or method invocation across threads is that Qt is unaware that your updates should be compressed. Every time you emit your signal connected to `QWidget::update()` in a separate thread, or every time you call `invokeMethod`, there is an event posted to an event queue.

The idiomatic, if undocumented, way of doing an across-threads update is:

```
QApplication::postEvent(widget,
                        new QEvent(QEvent::UpdateRequest),
                        Qt::LowEventPriority);
```

The UpdateRequest events get compressed by Qt. At any time, there can be only one such event in the event queue for a particular widget. So, once you post first such an event, the subsequent ones will be ignored until the widget actually consumes the event and repaints (updates) itself.

So, how about our various widget-setting calls, such as, for example `QLabel::setText()`? Surely it would be cool if we could somehow compress those as well? Yes, it is certainly possible, but we have to limit ourselves to public Qt interfaces. Qt doesn't offer anything obvious here.

The key is to remove any pending `QMetaCallEvent` from the widget's event queue before posting another one. This is safe only if we're sure that the queued signal-slot connections to given widget are only coming from us. This is usually a safe assumption, because everything in the GUI thread uses automatic connections, and those will default to directly invoking the slots without posting events to the event queue of the GUI thread.

Here's how:

```
QCoreApplication::removePostedEvents(label, QEvent::MetaCall);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(label, "setText", Q_ARG(QString, "foo"));
```

Note that for performance reasons we use a normalized representation of the slot: no extra spaces, and all `const Type &` are converted to simply `Type`.

Note: In my own projects, I sometimes use private Qt event compression APIs, but I won't advocate doing that here.

### Postscriptum

The C code should not be calling `QObject::connect`, I think it's a sign of bad design. If you want to communicate from the C code to the Qt code, use the static `QCoreApplication::postEvent(...)` (suitably wrapped/exposed to C, of course). To communicate the other way, you can hand-code an event queue in your thread(s). At a minimum, the "event queue" will be just a fixed structure, but the point is to use a mutex to protect access to it.

Another sign of bad design is that code external to a GUI class depends on the individual UI items within that class itself. You should provide a set of signals and slots on the overall UI class (say your `MainWindow`), and forward those to relevant UI elements internally. You can `connect()` signals to signals, but not slots to slots -- you'll have to code the forwarding slots manually.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, the problem was not mainly about the QT code here. My C code is, in fact, C++ code (otherwise, syntax like QObject:connect() would have been forbidden), just not QT code. What happens, my "C" thread uses a special-purpose class whose single purpose is to emit signals (being a descendant of QObjects) towards the QT thread. It is this class that is instantiated, then connected to various QT GUI elements. Interfacing C code with QT code, especially on multi-threading and *not* using QThreads seems to be a not-so-easy task.

Comment: [cont] Defining a special-purpose, QObject-derived class is the best solution that I found so far. Basically, emitting signals from this class does nothing more just calling the QCoreApplication::postEvent() method, but this happens behind the door, using the QT's signal and slots mechanism.

Comment: That's true, but if you'd use `postEvent()`, you don't need to derive from QObject, and you don't need to instantiate a special class either :)

Comment: I take the opportunity to ask for a little help: I am using that special class to simply emit a signal towards the slot update() of a QWidget (a QLabel). First, I was simply calling myLabel.update() from another thread, then I wished for a more Qt-thread-safe and Qt-like approach, so the special class was born. It simply emits a signal connected to the update() slot of myLabel. Now, the big question is: what is the correct QCoreApplication::postEvent() function call to trigger the update() slot of myLabel? And, is this thread-safe? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for such enlightening answer (err, above, not below :). I already have an accepted answer, I cannot accept two, but I vote yours up. I will try the suggested solutions. It is the first time that I see those so clearly explained. However, I partially disagree with the fact that calling QObject::connect() is a bad design, since you cannot really interface with QT without using at least one function of... QT. I also find "To communicate the other way, you can hand-code an event queue in your thread(s)." to be overkill and not practical, connect() is much easier.

Comment: But I fully agree with "sign of bad design is that code external to a GUI class depends on the individual UI items within that class itself", just that was not my priority for the task at hand. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer, it should be postered on the qt-project.org webpage.

Comment: You can always un-accept an answer and accept a different one :)

Comment: Using `QObject::connect()` would be bad design since it'd force you to create QObject classes in non-Qt code for no other reason but to emit signals. Using static methods is a cleaner approach -- it's exactly what you want to do, in fact. You want to call a function that will queue a method invocation in the event queue of the receiving QObject (really its QThread's queue, but that's a technicality). You can trivially create C wrappers around those static methods, and passing pointers to QObjects to your C code is easy, too.

Comment: "You can always un-accept an answer and accept a different one :)" That would be true, but the original question was rather about pthread_cond_broadcast(), not really about QT. Your answer is very valuable, still. "force you to create QObject classes in non-Qt code for no other reason but to emit signals" that is not true, I only instantiate a special class provided by what I coded like a C-to-QT interfacing library. Yes, I need to include the QT header and use some idioms (notably the SIGNAL() and SLOT() macros).

Comment: But I would also need the QT headers for calling QCoreApplication::postEvent(). I could wrap the calls towards the class methods in C functions, but it would be overkill for my needs. Generally, I would have ended using your approach, except that most of the GUI update examples that I found on the net are based rather on signal-slots except on posting events (I did not even know that QEvent::UpdateRequest is the event for widget repaint). SInce signals-slots seemed to do the work, I followed that approach and encapsulated it to suit my needs.